# Insert operation on Queap Data Structure

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, tree, priority-queue

I'm trying to create a `Queap` data structure described on Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queap)
I'm stuck in implementation of `Insert` operation because of lack of information.The operation `Insert` described there seems to set a bit of data from the `element` which is gonna be inserted

```
 public static void Insert(Queap Q, Element x) {
            if (Q.n == 0)
                    Q.minL = x;
            Q.l.add(x);
            x.inList = true;
            if (x.compareTo(Q.minL) < 0)
                    Q.minL = x;
    }
```

The operation seems to have complexity `O(1)` as it is described there : *The cost of the operation is O(1). The size of list L grows by one, the potential increases by some constant c.*.But if the element is an `int` value how can I set this?

Comment: Are you having problems with this in two programming languages?

Comment: @juanchopanza My implementation is in c/c++ . But the example from wikipedia is written in java

Comment: So, three languages.

Comment: @juanchopanza I actually don't understand the insert operation from the algorithm.It doesn't matter the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queap#Description):

> To add element `x` to list `l`, the element `x` is added to the end of the list and a bit variable in element `x` is set to one. This operation is done to determine if the element is either in the list or in a 2-4 tree.

You ask:

> But if the element is an `int` value how can I set this?

An element in the queap doesn't correspond directly to an instance of the data type being stored (in your case, an `int`).

Instead, an element corresponds to a combination of:

- an instance of the data type being stored, and
- a boolean flag indicating whether the element is in the list or in the 2-4 tree.

This could be represented using a `struct`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Element {
  T value;
  bool in_list;
};
```

Or using a `pair`:

```
template <typename T>
using Element = std::pair<T, bool>;
```

Comment: Thank you.It is now clear to me.

Comment: Birtch Tree but what about Delete operation ? There we must specify the whole element?How does the user know where is stored the element ?